# System.Exception: Too many record type describes: 101

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am getting a exception

```
System.Exception: Too many record type describes: 101
```

I understand this is a governor limit exception.

There are couple of places where i am checking for record types in a If statement in the trigger.

```
for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new)
{
   if ( ( o.TotalOpportunityQuantity != Trigger.OldMap.get(o.Id).TotalOpportunityQuantity) && o.RecordTypeId == varRectype) 
     {
                 // do something
     }

     // i am also checking in another if statement for o.RecordTypeId == varRectype with a combination of other fields.

 }
```

Has anybody else got this error. Any pointers on what is causing this would be of great help

Comment: This may be a case where you have to divide and conquer the issue by commenting large amounts of code out until you can narrow down the cause.

Comment: thanks @Will , i cant see anything other than 2 if statements referring to recordtype. We have been running this code for sometime on prodn and it just came up now.. I want to understand what this error means

Comment: I don't think stuff like o.RecordTypeId counts against this limit. Do you have anything in your code using getDescribe(), like this: Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the Developer Console, and repeat the action that caused this exception.  Then look at the debug log, to see at which point this Exception is firing.  The code you listed above should not be triggering this governor limit, as it has nothing to do with "describe".

Also, do you have any managed packages installed?  The code in those could be triggering this governor limit.  Debug log would tell you more.